# How to limit scope for XPath

Tags: java, android, xpath, xmlpullparser

I need to parse relatively big XML files on Android.

Some node internal structure contains HTML tags, for some other nodes I need to pull content from different depth levels. Therefore, instead of using XmlPullParser I plan to:

- using XPath, find the proper node
- using 'getElementsByTagName' find appropriate sub-node(s)
- extract information and save it in my custom data objects.

The problem I have is performance. The way how I open file is following:

```
        File file = new File(_path);
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NamespaceContext context = new NamespaceContextMap("def", __URL__);
        xPath.setNamespaceContext(context);

        Object objs = xPath.evaluate("/def:ROOT_ELEMENT/*,
            new InputSource(is), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Even though I need to get few strings that are in the very beginning of the XML file, it looks like XPath parses WHOLE xml file and put it in DOM structure.

In some cases I need access to full object and it is ok to have operation running few seconds for few megabyte file.

In other cases - I only need to get few nodes and don't want users to wait for my program to perform a redundant parsing.

**Q1: What is the way to get some parts of XML file without parsing it in full?**

**Q2: Is there any way to restrict XPath from scanning/parsing WHOLE XML file? For instance: scan till 2nd level of depth?**

Thank you.

P.S. In one particular case, XML file represents FB2 file format and if you have any specific tips that could resolve my problem for fb2-files parsing, please fill free to add additional comments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about the XML toolset available for android, except to know that it's painfully limited!

Probably the best way to tackle this requirement is to write a streaming SAX filter that looks for the parts of the document you are interested in, and builds a DOM containing only those parts, which you can then query using XPath. I'm a bit reluctant to advise that, because it won't be easy if you haven't done such things before, but it seems the right approach.

Comment: That sounds like there are no easy solution and I should literally implement own XML parser/scanner and if I got node I need to skip then I just quickly bypass till the closing tag for this node (handling 'CDATA' blocks properly)...

Comment: No, don't do that! Working with the SAX stream can be tricky, but if you try to write your own parser you will get it badly wrong and people will hate you for it.

Comment: SAX stream that is in fact the same what XmlPullParser offers. The problem with it is that I will get too many events for redundant nodes of HTML content which often is a content of XML node. I would like to avoid getting callbacks on such tags...

Comment: Kay, may be there is a way to avoid getting callback on 'insignificant' nodes? Thank you for you help anyway!

Comment: Oh, in fact you've written you have no experience with XML for Android... literally XmlPullParser is what you recommend.. and I should probably enhance it...

Comment: SAX is a push model, XmlPullParser is pull. Personally, I prefer push parsers, where it's very easy to write a filter that gets rid of the events you aren't interested in. But it's possible to do that with a pull parser too: just a bit trickier.

Comment: AX parser is essentially the same as XmlPullParser: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html as far as I understood the only difference is either to use callbacks that will be called by parser (SAX) or to use 'next' to come to the next element. Technically they both scan and I should take care to ignore HTML tags (that are required to be ignored for my case).

Comment: Yes, at one level of abstraction push parsing and pull parsing are essentially the same. At the concrete programming level, however, they are very different.

Comment: Yup. Anyway thank you for your help, at least I learned about another way to do Xml parsing.